# (Java) Setting a new default UI object as early as possible

Tags: java, user-interface, progress

I've made a custom progress bar UI class that extends **BasicProgressBarUI**. I know I can change the UI of a progress bar simply by invoking `progressBar.setUI()`. However, I'm thinking this is a waste of processing time as the environment has already initialized the default UI object.

My question is therefore: how can I as early as possible in an application set some property that makes all progress bars use as a default my own progress bar UI? If I have to create some more classes to do this, this is of course fine.

Thanks for an answer!